# responseXML = null error by XMLHttpRequest

Tags: html, ajax, xml

I want to make this example http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xml2 work on my server but I always get responseXML = null and I don't know why?
When I copy html and xml files to my server and try in browser I get:

```
    onabort:null
    onerror:null
    onload:null
    onloadend:null
    onloadstart:null
    onprogress:null
    onreadystatechange:()
    ontimeout:null
    readyState:4
    response:"..."
    responseText:"..."
    responseType:""
    responseURL:"http://www.domainname.com/file.xml"
    responseXML:null
    status:200
    statusText:"OK"
    timeout:0
    upload:XMLHttpRequestUpload
    withCredentials:false
    __proto__:XMLHttpRequest
```

I test it in Chrome, IE and Opera. Files are in the same dir. What I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us some code so we can see the error in action.

Comment: I copy the code from link above and xml file an I get the same error on localhost and two different server where I made test: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
    at myFunction (catalog.html:39)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange (catalog.html:29)
myFunction @ catalog.html:39
xhttp.onreadystatechange @ catalog.html:29

Answer (score 1):

Works! My .xml file have empty first line and that couse the error. I didn't notice that.